# Replace content in PDF "binary" and save - vb.net

Tags: vb.net, pdf, binary-data

I need to add some information to a PDF (Trim Box proporties, actually replace Media Box proporties with Media Box and Trim Box proporties), and I dont have the support in my PDF-motor. So I found out that I can use Notepad++ to open the PDF as a text file and simply add the Trim Box proporties as a string and save it. Now I want to do it automatically with vb.net. When I use Stream Reader/Writer the PDF gets destroyed and loses information (Stream Reader dont read all the NUL, SOH, STX etc. I guess). I tried to read the PDF using ReadAllBytes/WriteAllBytes and then it works good, but then I don't know how to replace "Media Box ..." with "Media Box... Trim Box...". I try to use IndexOf but I can only search for single Byte not the whole string. I'm not good in binary and thats perhaps the problem :-). Does anyone have a better way doing it or how do I search for my string "Media Box" in binary?

Thanks!

/Georg

Answer (score 0):

if you succeed to get the pdf in a string, look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1(v=VS.90).aspx#Y1420 to locate (sub)strings in a string

and I use this to convert bytes to string:

```
        Dim buf(ssd.SrcLength - 1) As Byte
        EditRdFile = ReadFile(ssd.SrcFileIx)
        EditRdFile.Seek(ssd.SrcStart - 1, SeekOrigin.Begin)
        EditRdFile.Read(buf, 0, ssd.SrcLength)
        If CurrEdtSession.IsUnicode Then
            Dim enc As System.Text.Encoding = New System.Text.UnicodeEncoding(False, True, True)
            value = enc.GetString(buf)
        Else
            value = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(buf)
        End If
```

from my editor, that handles ansi and unicodefiles